# Display disk space needed for upgrade

Tags: rhel, yum, disk-usage

I'm using Red Hat 7. In order to create an update/upgrade script, I'd like to know if there is a way to know the disk space that will be needed for an upgrade. I need to know for each used partition (for example /boot and /var) the disk space the updated packages will take. The goal is to check (maybe using `df`) if the upgrade is ok to go.

In summary: how much disk space will take the upgrade and on wich partition(s)?

The only documentation I've found is [here](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1320213), and I don't have any credentials.

Comment: I fail to see how my question can be a duplicate of this one.

Answer (score 2):

Well, that document would only tell you what probably doesn't surprise you, that you can manually look at the output of `yum update` and then answer "no" to the install confirmation (and there is a `--assumeno` switch in 7 which is like a reversed `--assumeyes`).

My experience with CentOS7 is that beyond that: no, it does not know how much space it needs, in particular, `yum` will happily fail to re-build your initrd if your `/boot` is too small. (The vendor "fix" for that is "um, yeah, but we're upping the recommended size of `/boot` to 1G in new installs", if I recall correctly.)

So as far as `/boot` is concerned, I'd say: hardcode conservative values, unfortunately.